# Vue detect click outside when component is rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I implemented the [vue-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-click-outside) package in my application. Everything is working fine when I click on the button the filter opens and when I am clicking outside the component it closes. However after the first rotation is finished, if i click on the button again the click outside function also fires off and the button wont open.

My child/filter component:

```
<div class="filter-container" v-click-outside="closeDropdown">

closeDropdown() {
      this.$emit("closeDropdown");
    },
```

My parent component:

```
<button @click="toggleFilter()">Filter</button>
<FilterDropdown v-if="showFilter" v-on:closeDropdown="closeDropdown"></FilterDropdown>

closeDropdown() {
      this.showFilter = false;
    },
toggleFilter() {
      this.showFilter = !this.showFilter;
    },
```

Comment: When do you reset `this.showFilter` to `true`?

Comment: I edited my post so it is more clear.